# C++ operator overloading for myClass(x,y,z) = value

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In C++, how should I overload the function call operator in order that an instance of my class can take in such an expression: `myClass(x,y,z) = value` ?

I have a template class Array3D, which is used as a wrapper for a 1D array. I want to set a specif value at a certain index in this array. Till now I used to do it with a regular function like so: 
`array.setValueAt(int x, int y, int z, int value)` 
but now I wanted to overload the function call operator and use it instead. So something like that:
`array(x, y, z) = value`

Comment: What do you mean "map to member" ?

Comment: I meant that there is an equivalent member variable in the class which would be assigned using those parameters.

Comment: What means "equivalent" ? Does `myClass(x,y,z)` will have the same behavior as `myClass(z,y,x)`?

Comment: Even if that does not compile write a simple example with expected behavior clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the function call operator, `operator()`:

```
struct Foo
{
    int & operator()(int, int, int) { return x; }
    int x;
};
```

You should make it return an lvalue (or otherwise something which overloads assignment) in order for your assignment example to work.

Usage:

```
Foo a;
a(1, 2, 3) = 10;

assert(a.x == 10);
```

Comment: if 'x' was not the only member. Say I have myValue0, myValue1, myValue2, which are of the same type, but I want this operator to affect only one of them. Is that method going to work?

Comment: @G.Rassovsky: Well, overloaded operators are just functions, so whatever makes sense for ordinary functions can be applied here.

Comment: I see, however my specific problem is: I have a template class Array3D, which is used as a wrapper for a 1D array. I want to set a specif value at a certain index in this array. Till now I used to do it with a regular function like so: 
setValueAt(int x, int y, int z, int value), but now I wanted to overload the function call operator and use it instead. Sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: @G.Rassovsky: Put the details in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If your class holds values of some type `ValueType`, you can return a reference to it:

`ValueType & operator () (int x, int y, int z);`

assuming you are indexing with `int`. For completeness, you might find it convenient to add:

`const ValueType & operator () (int x, int y, int z) const;`

for const access to the value.